# Jerky/Jittery Camera Movement in Unity FPS Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, game-engine, game-development

I'm currently working on an FPS Game in Unity and I created the Player/Camera Movement but now when I move the Camera in playmode it's very jerky/jittery.

That's what I have already done:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform orientation;

    float horizontalInput;
    float verticalInput;

    Vector3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;
    
    private void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    private void Update(){
        MyInput();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate(){
        MovePlayer();
    }

    private void MyInput(){
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void MovePlayer(){
        // calculate movement direction
        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;

        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCam : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;

    public Transform orientation;

    float xRotation;
    float yRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Update(){
        // get mouse input
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

        yRotation += mouseX;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        // rotate cam and orientation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
        orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;

    void Update() {
        transform.position = player.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
I would really appreciate it.
If you need more information just ask.

I really don't know what to do.